# Set width and height to responsive Google Map?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, responsive-design

To be able to view the Google Maps, I have to set the height to a pixel value. I can set the width to 100% and it's almost responsive, but not to the height. I thought I could set different values to the height depending on different media queires, but that doesn't work. Any ideas how this can be solved. I just want a smaller height when it's on mobile and a bigger map on desktop.

The CSS I use:

```
#map-canvas
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

media query works perfectly.

`look here`

try to re-size window with the map inside.

Comment: Hmmm, but I guess this will only work if all the code is embedded like your example code? What if I have Google Maps the other way if you understand what I mean!?

Comment: Nice! It's seems like this is working! I tested this my self, but I must have made some miner error because it didnät workt then. I have only tested this by resizing the browser, but will it work nice on real mobile devices also?

Comment: Yes. It will work. You just need to play with devices size. Here for example a list of Media Queries for Standard Devices  :  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

you can use java Script or jQuery 
like this

```
var wi = window.innerWidth;
var he = window.innerHeight;
$('#map-canvas').css('width',wi+'px');
$('#map-canvas').css('height',he+'px');
```